# How to add same method with 2 different names in GNU Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

How can I have a class expose the same method with 2 different names?

E.g. that the `asDescripton` function does the same thing / re-exports the `asString` function without simply copy-pasting the code.

```
Object subclass: Element [
  | width height |

  Element class >> new [
    ^super new init.
  ]

  init [
    width := 0.
    height := 0.
  ]

  asString [
    ^ 'Element with width ', width, ' and height ', height.
  ]

  asDescription [ "???" ]
]
```

Comment: You could just call the `asString` selector from `asDescription`: `asDescription [ ^ asString ]`.

Comment: Please accept the answer when it suits your needs - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Smalltalk you usually implement `#printOn:` and get `#asString` from the inherited version of it which goes on the lines of

```
Object >> asString
  | stream |
  stream := '' writeStream.
  self printOn: stream.
  ^stream contents
```

The actual implementation of this method may be slightly different in your environment, the idea remains the same.

As this is given, it is usually a good idea to implement `#printOn:` rather than `#asString`. In your case you would have it implemented as

```
Element >> printOn: aStream
  aStream
    nextPutAll: 'Element with width ';
    nextPutAll: width asString;
    nextPutAll: ' and height ';
    nextPutAll: height asString
```

and then, as JayK and luker indicated,

```
Element >> asDescription
  ^self asString
```

In other words, you (usually) don't want to implement `#asString` but `#printOn:`. This approach is better because it takes advantage of the inheritance and ensures consistency between `#printOn:` and `#asString`, which is usually expected. In addition, it will give you the opportunity to start becoming familiar with `Streams`, which play a central role in Smalltalk.

Note by the way that in my implementation I've used `width asString` and `heigh asString`. Your code attempts to concatenate (twice) a `String` with a `Number`:

```
'Element with width ', width, ' and height ', height.
```

which won't work as you can only concatenate instances of `String` with `#,`.

In most of the dialects, however, you can avoid sending `#asString` by using `#print:` instead of `#nextPutAll:`, something like:

```
Element >> printOn: aStream
  aStream
    nextPutAll: 'Element with width ';
    print: width;
    nextPutAll: ' and height ';
    print: height
```

which is a little bit less verbose and therefore preferred.

One last thing. I would recommend changing the first line above with this one:

```
    nextPutAll: self class name;
    nextPutAll: ' with width ';
```

instead of hardcoding the class name. This would prove to be useful if in the future you subclass `Element` because you will have no need to tweak `#printOn:` and any of its derivatives (e.g., `#asDescription`).

Final thought: I would rename the selector `#asDescription` to be `#description`. The preposition `as` is intended to convert an object to another of a different class (this is why `#asString` is ok). But this doesn't seem to be the case here.

## Addendum: Why?

There is a reason why `#asString` is implemented in terms of `#printOn:`, and not the other way around: *generality*. While the effort (code complexity) is the same, `#printOn:` is clearly a winner because it will work with *any* character `Stream`. In particular, it will work with no modification whatsoever with

1. Files (instances of `FileStream`)
2. Sockets (instances of `SocketStream`)
3. The `Transcript`

In other words, by implementing `#printOn:` one gets `#asString` for free (inheritance) and --at the same time-- the ability to dump a representation of the object on files and sockets. The `Transcript` is particularly interesting because it supports the `Stream` protocol for writing, and thus can be used for testing purposes before sending any bytes to external devices.

### **Remember!**

In Smalltalk, the goal is to have objects whose behavior is simple and **general** at once, **not just simple!**

Comment: Oh interesting. I was doing it actually the other way round: I implemented `printOn` in terms of `asString`. Felt more natural coming from a Haskell background.

Comment: @adius Read the Addendum for some more thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2):

As lurker wrote in the comments, send the asString message in asDescription.

```
asDescription
    ^ self asString
```

This is usually done to expose additional interfaces/protocols from a class, for compatibility or as a built-in adapter. If you create something new that does not have to fit in anywhere else, consider to stick to just one name for each operation.

Edit: if you really are after the re-export semantics and do not want the additional message sends involved in the delegation above, there might be a way to put the CompiledMethod of asString in the method dictionary of the class a second time under the other name. But neither am I sure that this would work, nor do I know the protocol in GNU Smalltalk how to manipulate the method dictionary. Have a look at the documentation of the `Behavior` class. Also, I would not consider this as programming Smalltalk, but tinkering with the system.

Comment: I think that CompiledMethod retains a pointer to method selector in st80 and descendants. it's mostly for decompiling or retrieving source code (in a debugger), but maybe there is another use that I missed. So I can't tell if there would be a side effect of sharing same compiledMethod in two different selector entries in methodDictionary. Worth a try...